# a calendar display issue on Symfony2: the calendar can't be displayed

Tags: symfony, calendar

I installed CalendarBundle by following the tutorial on this link: https://github.com/carlescliment/calendar-bundle , but the problem is that the calendar can't be displayed whenever I try to display it. By the way, this is the script of the html.twig file which should display the calendar:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/bladetestercalendar/css/calendar-header.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/bladetestercalendar/css/calendar.css') }}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bladetestercalendar/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js') }}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bladetestercalendar/js/calendar.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="app">
                <header class="main-header">
                    {% block header %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </header>


                <div class="main-body">
                    {% block body %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>

                <footer class="main-footer">
                    {% block footer %}
                        <p>Opensourced by <a href="#">&reg;Vetaminic</a></p>
                    {% endblock %}
                </footer>
            </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

So, what shall I do to resolve this problem? I have tried to find a solution but it was in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you made all the step in the bundle documentation ? Some errors appear in the developer tool ?

Comment: Yes I did all the steps and no errors appeared in the developer tool.